# Can I write multiple DataFrames in parallel in Spark?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I have question i want to sequentially write many dataframe in avro format and i use the code below in a for loop.

```
df
  .repartition(<number-of-partition>)
  .write 
  .mode(<write-mode>)
  .avro(<file-path>)
```

The problem is when i run my spark job , I see at a time only one task is getting executed (so , only 1 data frame is getting written) .
Also when I checked the number of active executors in the spark-ui , I see only 1 executor is being used.

Is it possible to write DataFrames in parallel in Spark?
If yes am i doing it the good way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If your question has been correctly answered, consider marking the answer as accepted (like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)) so that it can help future people that come across the same issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You ask if you can write dataframes sequentially in spark, but as I understand your question, you rather would like to write them in parallel don't you? (You already write them sequentially as you do that in a for loop)

One method to write them in parallel is to create a parallelized collection of dataframe with `.par`, and use a `foreach` to write them all in parallel:

```scala
val dfList = Seq(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
// sequential version
dfList.zipWithIndex.foreach(x => x._1.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s"/tmp/dataframe_${x._2}"))
// parallel version
dfList.par.zipWithIndex.foreach(x => x._1.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s"/tmp/dataframe_${x._2}"))
```

Here is a timeline to compare the sequential and the parallel methods:
[image: Comparison of sequential and parallel writing]

EDIT: I'm using parquet format but using avro format should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

To run multiple parallel jobs, you need to submit them from separate threads:

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads. By “job”, in this section, we mean a Spark action (e.g. save, collect) and any tasks that need to run to evaluate that action.

You can check [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) for more details.

As for the single executor problem, it depends on several factors, like:

- the number of partitions in your df
- the number of executors added to your session (`spark.executor.instances`)

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct. However, here's another approach using Scala [Futures](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

You can find an elaborate explanation here, about this approach: http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/02/27/Concurrency-In-Spark/

You will see that the respective output directories are indeed outputted at around the same time, rather than sequentially.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

def write(df:DataFrame, i:Int) =
    df.repartition(5).write.mode("overwrite").avro(s"/path/to/output_$i")

val dataframes = Iterator(df, df2) // replace with a list of your data frames

// This is the line that "executes" the writes in parallel
// Use dataframes.zipWithIndex.map to create an iterator/list of futures
// Use Future.sequence to compose together all of these futures, into one future
// Use Await.result to wait until this "composite" future completes
Await.result(Future.sequence(Iterator(df, df2).zipWithIndex.map{ case (d, i) => Future(write(d, i))}), Inf)
```

You can set a timeout (other than `Inf`), and also batch together sublists of dataframes, if needed, to limit the parallelism.